# SwingMetawidget, value not getting bound to JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, metawidget

I am using `SwingMetawidget`. My data structure has a `Person` class and one of the properties is a `Title` which is also a class with a Many To One relationship from `Person` to `Title`. 
I am trying to get a `JComboBox` in the MetaWidget with the value of the Title bound. I am getting the list of values I specify through the lookup, but the value in the inspection object is not getting selected in the Edit Mode. In the Read Only mode, the right value is displayed (I have set up a converter from Title to `String`).

My code is below. What am I missing?

**Read Only Mode where Title is displayed:**

[image]

**Edit Mode, but the value "Mr" not selected:**

[image]

**Edit Mode, All lookup values displayed:**

[image]

**Main Class:**

```
public class MetaWidgetFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private SwingMetawidget metawidget = new SwingMetawidget();
    private JPanel contentPanel;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MetaWidgetFrame frame = new MetaWidgetFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MetaWidgetFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 473, 281);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        contentPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel controlsPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        contentPane.add(controlsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                savePerson();
            }
        });
        controlsPanel.add(btnSave);


        // Set up the objects 
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setUserID(new Integer(1));
        person.setFirstName("Raman");
        person.setLastName("C V");

        Title title = new Title();
        title.setTitleId(new Integer(1));
        title.setName("Mr");


        // Configure Inspectors 
        CompositeInspectorConfig inspectorConfig = new CompositeInspectorConfig().setInspectors(
                  new JpaInspector()
                , new PropertyTypeInspector()
                ,new MetawidgetAnnotationInspector()
                );

        BeansBindingProcessorConfig bbpc = new BeansBindingProcessorConfig();

        // Set up the converter from Title to String
        bbpc.setConverter(Title.class, String.class, new Converter<Title,String>() {
            @Override
            public String convertForward(Title title) {
                return title.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public Title convertReverse(String title) {
                if ( title == null || "".equals( title ) ) {
                    return null;
                }
                Title titleObj = new Title(title,null,null,1,1);
                return titleObj;
            }

        });

        BeansBindingProcessor bbp = new BeansBindingProcessor(bbpc);        

        metawidget.setInspector( new CompositeInspector( inspectorConfig ) );
        metawidget.addWidgetProcessor(new ReflectionBindingProcessor());
        metawidget.addWidgetProcessor(bbp);

        GridBagLayoutConfig gbc = new GridBagLayoutConfig();
        gbc.setLabelAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        gbc.setRequiredText("");
        gbc.setRequiredAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        gbc.setLabelSuffix(": ");
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout(gbc);

        metawidget.setMetawidgetLayout(gbl);

        metawidget.setToInspect(person);

        contentPanel.add(metawidget, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JXLabel hintLabel = new JXLabel("New label");
        contentPanel.add(hintLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JGoodiesValidatorProcessorIMPL jgProcessor = new JGoodiesValidatorProcessorIMPL().setHintLabel(hintLabel);      
        metawidget.addWidgetProcessor(jgProcessor);

        //add a component to show validation messages
        JComponent validationResultsComponent = jgProcessor.getValidationResultsComponent();

        JPanel errorsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        contentPanel.add(errorsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        errorsPanel.add(validationResultsComponent,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }

    public void savePerson() {
        JGoodiesValidatorProcessorIMPL validationProcessor = metawidget.getWidgetProcessor(JGoodiesValidatorProcessorIMPL.class);
        ValidationResult result = validationProcessor.showValidationErrors().getValidationResults();
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            metawidget.getWidgetProcessor(BeansBindingProcessor.class).save(metawidget );
            Person personSaved = metawidget.getToInspect();
            System.out.println("" + personSaved);
        }
        pack();
    }
    public JPanel getContentPanel() {
        return contentPanel;
    }
}
```

**Person Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person", catalog = "mydb")
public class Person {

    private Integer userID;
    private Title title;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person() {
    }       

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "userID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    @UiLookup (value={"Mr","Ms","Miss","Mrs"})
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "titleID", nullable = false)
    public Title getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @UiSection ("Others")
    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public void setTitle(Title title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person: "
                + "\n userID = " + userID  
                + "\n title = " + title
                + "\n titleID = " + title.getTitleId()                  
                + "\n firstName = " + firstName  
                + "\n lastName = " + lastName;
    }


}
```

**Title Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "title", catalog = "emisdb")
public class Title implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer titleId;
    private String name;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Date modifiedDate;
    private int createdBy;
    private int modifiedBy;
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(0);

    public Title() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
    public Title(String name, Date createdDate, Date modifiedDate, int createdBy, int modifiedBy) {
        this.name = name;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    public Title(String name, Date createdDate, Date modifiedDate, int createdBy, int modifiedBy, Set<User> users) {
        this.name = name;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "titleID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getTitleId() {
        return this.titleId;
    }

    public void setTitleId(Integer titleId) {
        this.titleId = titleId;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 4)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @UiHidden
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "createdDate", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @UiHidden
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "modifiedDate", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getModifiedDate() {
        return this.modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    @UiHidden
    @Column(name = "createdBy", nullable = false)
    public int getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(int createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @UiHidden
    @Column(name = "modifiedBy", nullable = false)
    public int getModifiedBy() {
        return this.modifiedBy;
    }
    public void setModifiedBy(int modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    @UiHidden
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "title")
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }
    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in Metawidget!

There are a number of general problems with your code, ranging from trivial to conceptually important. None of them are Metawidget problems, per se. I'll try to break them down:

### Trivial Problems

In `MetaWidgetFrame` you create `person = new Person()` and `title = new Title()` but you forget to do `person.setTitle( title )`.

### Conceptually Important 1

As your code stands, if you try:

```
Title title1 = new Title();
title1.setTitleId(new Integer(1));
title1.setName("Mr");

Title title2 = new Title();
title2.setTitleId(new Integer(1));
title2.setName("Mr");

System.out.println( title1 == title1 );       // will return true
System.out.println( title1.equals( title2 )); // will return false
```

You can see two `Title` objects, with identical fields, will not match using object equivalence (the `equals` method). BeansBinding, and most Java technologies, rely on object equivalence. So you need to override both the `equals` and the `hashCode` method of `Title`.

### Conceptually Important 2

In your `Converter`, you are trying to convert a String ('Mr') to a `Title` object by simply doing:

`titleObj = new Title(title,null,null,1,1);`

This sets the `name` to `title`, but the other fields are either not initialized (`null`) or initialized to an arbitrary value (`1`). In particular, the `id` is not initialized. Depending on how you implement the `equals` and `hashCode` methods (see above), this means they will never match the record that comes back from the database.

### Conclusion

I fixed all 3 of these and the code works as expected. However your particular implementation will vary. In particular you probably need to do a database lookup in your `Converter`. Or, ideally, do a database lookup once per session and cache the list of title objects.

As an aside, having a `OneToMany` on `Title` might be over-normalized (i.e. will result in a lot of database joins). You may be better just storing `Title` as a String within each `Person`. You can still have a `Title` object that is used so that you can configure the list of possible titles in the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and detailed reply. I implemented the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods and changed the Converter as suggested. It works like a Charm :). In my main project, I am caching the `Title` objects from the DB and using it. I will consider your point on over Normalizing the `Person` to `Title` relationship. Based on your help on the other thread, I implemented the JGoodies Validation by extending the `JGoodiesValidatorProcessor`and it works well. Once I am done with my project, I can share the extensions so that it will be helpful for other fans of MetaWidget.